AWS Fargate caching ECR tags?
I use the "latest" tag when pushing an image to ECR. I stop the task in the UI, expecting that when the Task is automatically restarted by Fargate that this "latest" image will be used, but instead it uses the old one. What am I missing? I have been using this method for years, and it only just stopped working.
I am using this documentation, but the text doesn't actually say anything about whether the task is cached:

Every Fargate task runs on its own single use, single tenant instance. When you run Linux containers on Fargate, container images or container image layers are not cached on the instance. Therefore, for each container image defined in the task, the whole container image needs to be pulled from the container image registry for each Fargate task.

If I delete the old image it of course causes a CannotPullContainerError.
A workaround would be to change the task definitions, updating from using "latest" to using the images' sha but I'd prefer to find out if I'm doing something wrong first. Another might be to "force deploy" - I will try that first.

Force redeploy works. With 100s of services, I can script out enumerating them all.

That's always been a problem with EC2 deployments, but I'm a bit surprised it is a problem with Fargate deployments. Image caching is actually a requested feature for Fargate, but it hasn't been implemented yet https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/696 So I'm not sure what would have caused the issue you ran into. Of course best practice is to use the image SHA, or immutable image tags, instead of latest to always avoid this sort of thing.

It looks like this feature is causing the behavior you are seeing. It looks like ECS stores the image hash now, at deployment time, and doesn't look for new versions of your latest image until you trigger another deployment. I highly recommend you switch away from using latest to using immutable image tags.
